# Undefined is null or not an object - Jquery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, undefined

I have an issue when using the jquery validate plugin with IE. I get the following error "undefined is null or not an object" when validating the form.

The error is at line 431 : " **$("#signup_meeta").submit();**"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#pseudobox").hide();
 $("#passwdbox").hide();
 $("#emailbox").hide();
 $("#sexebox").hide();
 $("#originbox").hide();
 $("#birthdaybox").hide();
 $("#countrybox").hide();
 $("#regionbox").hide();
 $("#dptbox").hide();
 $("#acceptbox").hide();

 $("#dpt").hide();

 dynamicSelectRegion(); 
 $("#fromc").change(function() {
   dynamicSelectRegion();
 });

 $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();

 $("#signup_meeta").validate({
  ignore : ":hidden",
  rules: {
   nickname : {
    required : true,
    minlength : 5,
    maxlength : 15,
    remote : "?q=register/CheckUsername",
    nowhitespace : true,
    nospecialcar : true
   },
   passwd : {
    required : true,
    minlength : 5
   },
   email : {
    required : true,
    email : true,
    nowhitespace : true,
    nospecialcar : true
   },
   gender : {
    required : true
   },
   origin : {
    required : true
   },
   birth_day : {
    required : true
   },
   birth_month : {
    required : true
   },
   birth_year : {
    required : true
   },
   fromc : {
    required : true
   },
   region : {
    required : true
   },
   department : {
    required: true
   },
   accept_cgu : {
    required : true
   }
  },
  messages: {
   nickname : {
    required : "Veuillez entrer votre pseudo svp",
    minlength: "Votre pseudo doit contenir au - 5 caract&egrave;res",
    maxlength: "Votre pseudo doit contenir au + 15 caract&egrave;res",
    remote: "Ce pseudo n'est pas disponible. Modifiez svp",
    nowhitespace: "Ce champ ne doit pas contenir d\'espace",
    nospecialcar: "Ce champ ne doit pas contenir de caract&egrave;re sp&eacute;cial"
   },
   passwd : {
    required : "Veuillez entrer votre mot de passe svp",
    minlength: "Votre mot de passe doit contenir au - 5 caract&egrave;res"
   },
   email : {
    required : "Veuillez entrer votre adresse email svp",
    nowhitespace: "Ce champ ne doit pas contenir d\'espace",
    nospecialcar: "Ce champ ne doit pas contenir de caract&egrave;re sp&eacute;cial"
   },
   gender : {
    required : "Veuillez s&eacute;lectionner votre sexe svp"
   },
   origin : {
    required : "Veuillez s&eacute;lectionner votre pays d\'origine svp"
   },
   birth_day : {
    required : "  Votre jour de naissance ?"
   },
   birth_month : {
    required : "  Votre mois de naissance ?"
   },
   birth_year : {
    required : "  Votre ann&eacute;e de naissance ?"
   },
   fromc : {
    required : "Veuillez s&eacute;lectionner votre pays svp"
   },
   region : {
    required : "Veuillez s&eacute;lectionner votre r&eacute;gion svp"
   },
   department : {
    required : "Veuillez s&eacute;lectionner votre d&eacute;partement svp"
   },
   accept_cgu : {
    required : "Veuillez accepter les CGUs svp" 
   }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
   **$("#signup_meeta").submit();**
   return false;
  }

 });

})
```

Can someone help me please ?

Best regards,
Salim

Answer (score 1):

You should call the native [`form.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit) method to avoid errors and an infinite loop here, like this:

```
form.submit();
```

The validation plugin, by default, adds a [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler on the `<form>` element, so triggering that event in the `submitHandler` would cause validation to run again, pass again, rinse/repeat, and loop infinitely.  If you look at the [`submitHandler` documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) it mentions this specifically:

> Use submitHandler to process something and then using the default submit. Note that "form" refers to a DOM element, this way the validation isn't triggered again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer ! it has solved my issue :)

Comment: @Salim - Be sure to comment if it didn't resolve the problem, or accept the answer via the check on the left if it did :)